# Why not use a default 2 or 4 MB stack size in C++ Builder 64 bit applications?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

This is mainly out of curiosity, perhaps there's a good reason I'm not aware of ?
The question is also born out of the fact that I ran into a stack overflow because of a weird data-set that caused a function to call itself a large number of times.  An easy fix was to increase the stack size until I have time to 'properly' fix this issue.

I fixed it by setting the stack size to 2MB for 64 bit versions of the software.

I was surprised that it defaults to 1MB (for 64 bit Windows apps) on C++ Builder 11 ?  I read somewhere that C# 64 bit applications get 4MB by default ?

It makes sense to give 64 bit applications a bit more stack size, since for the same functionality (32 bit vs 64 bit), a 64 bit application will likely use more of the stack, especially if a lot of pointers are temporary stored.
So, to get equal functionality before the stack runs out, a 64 bit application should get more stack size to start with.

At least that's my take on it.

So I wonder why C++ Builder 64 bit defaults to 1MB ?

An oversight or very much on purpose ?

Comment: "*An oversight or very much on purpose ?*" - that is something you would have to ask Embarcadero directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Very much agree but being less sure of myself I suppose I was looking for some feedback before I possibly raise this.  It's also not really a bug, so I probably shouldn't report it as one, which leaves me clueless as to where to go with this.

Comment: "*which leaves me clueless as to where to go with this*" - to the source, the word of God, the vendor itself. Only they can answer for sure why things are the way they are.

Comment: FYI: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37131